# Incorrect JSON format sent from an app

Tags: java, android, json

How can I send JSONArray from Android client to server?
getJsonArray() is a function which return an **JsonArray** but when I send array to server it looks like this:

```
{
    "IMEI": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Puls": ["101", "125", "103", "81"],
    "Pasi": ["0", "0", "0", "0"],
    "Latitudine": ["0", "0", "0", "0"],
    "Longitudine": ["0IMEI=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "0IMEI=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "0IMEI=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "0"]   
}
```

I don't know why first IMEI is on right place and the others is not...

```
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

for (int i = 0; i < getJsonArray().length(); i++) {
    writer.write(getPostDataString(getJsonArray().getJSONObject(i)));
}
```

Comment: Add your expected json.

Comment: you don't write `JSONArray` to your `writer`. You write `JSONObject` one by one. Remove the cycle, and do only `writer.write(getPostDataString(getJsonArray()));` once

Comment: getPostDataString() method need JSONObject param, so...i can't put JSONArray :(

Answer (score 0):

The array inside the main array should look like this for example :-

```
"Puls": [
       {
        "number" : "101"
        },
      {
         "number" : "125"
        },
      {
         "number" : "103"
      },
     {
         "number" : "81"
     },
]
```

Try to format the arrays like this...

Comment: I don't see a single reason for it to look like you showed. Array of strings is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

String strloadMainCategory = "api"+URLEncoder.encode("","UTF-8");
  RestClient restClient = new RestClient(strloadMainCategory);
     try {`enter code here`
       restClient.Execute(RequestMethod.GET);
       } catch (Exception e) {}